# how do i send a command to execute on a terminal?

Tags: command-line, system, input

I am executing  `system ("./get_emotion.sh");` which opens a terminal and establishes some connections. Then it requires this input `set all evi` . I have tried using `&&` in `system()` to send input but it is not working. I want to enter this input `set all evi` using C code. can you please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `system ("echo \"set all evi\" | ./get_emotion.sh");`

Or `system ("./get_emotion.sh <<< \"set all evi\"");`

Comment: If you meant to redirect `set all evi` as a here string (which was way nicer and better than forking two subshells) you were just missing a `<`

Comment: @SalmanZafar The above is equivalent to executing `./get_emotion.sh` and entering this input. What input are you talking about?

Comment: Upvoted already ;) @SalmanZafar It would help to know which command is expecting the input. Please [add it to your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/645665/edit). Another option is to use `expect`, which AFAIK has also a `C` implementation

Comment: Thank you. `system ("echo \"set all evi\" | ./get_emotion.sh");`worked for me.

Comment: @SalmanZafar The other way should work as well, however if this answer solved your problem you should accept it by clicking the green tick under the votes count, that's how you deem an answer as working for you on Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @SalmanZafar: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**